# count number of children returned and push the children attribute into array using Cypress

Tags: javascript, each, cypress, children

I am trying to count the number of children returned when doing

`cy.xpath(NODE_PREVIEW_PANEL).children('data-testid')`

So that I can use the count to pass all the values into an array sequentially avoiding the async of `.each()` function.

How can I get the count of children here?

(or you can suggest a totally different solution)

Comment: Can you try this - `cy.xpath(NODE_PREVIEW_PANEL).children('data-testid').its('length').then((len) => {
    //Print Length
    cy.log(len)
})`

Comment: That kind of works, but I still have issue with mixing up sync and async code.

Comment: So what you are looking for is with iteration of `each()`, you want to push the position of the children element to the array ?

Comment: the problem can be put like this - "I am getting bunch of children from the DOM which I am processing using ```each()``` function. Using the same each function I am adding it to an array. But because of ```each()``` being async, it is returning the array before it adds all the elements to the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I use successfully is to use [reference variable](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0)

```
let variablesToValidate = {
    numberOfChildren: 0,
    attributes: []
}
cy.xpath(NODE_PREVIEW_PANEL)
    .children('data-testid')
    .each(($element, index, $array) =>{
        cy.wrap($element)
            .should('have.attr', 'attributeName')
            .then(atrributeValue => variablesToValidate.attributes.push(atrributeValue))
    })
    .then($array => variablesToValidate.numberOfChildren = $array.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index value to find the position of the element. You can do something like:

```
cy.xpath(NODE_PREVIEW_PANEL).children('data-testid').each((el, index) => {
    //It will give the position of the element  
    Array.push(index);
})
```